# C# Get Mouse handle (GetRawInputDeviceInfo)

Tags: c#, api

My goal should be a simple one... Grab the device handle for a mouse that fired a click event on my form (I have multiple mice).

On my form, I have patched into

```
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message message) {
```

...to ensure that no child controls get missed (this is working fine).

Within this routine, I'm calling a class that handles all the necessary API's to grab the device handle:

```
   public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message message) {
        switch (message.Msg) {
            case 0x0201: //LButtonDown
                int HardwareID = new clsGetInputID().GetDeviceID(message);
                break;
            case 0x204: //RButtonDown
                int HardwareID2 = new clsGetInputID().GetDeviceID(message);
                break;
   }
```

The HardwareID always shows a different number, even though I click with the same mouse.

I suspect I have some constants set up incorrectly, or I am marshalling them incorrectly.

```
class clsGetInputID {

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    extern static uint GetRawInputDeviceInfo(IntPtr hDevice, uint uiCommand, IntPtr pData, ref uint pcbSize);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    extern static uint GetRawInputData(IntPtr hRawInput, uint uiCommand, IntPtr pData, ref uint pcbSize, uint cbSizeHeader);


    private const int RID_INPUT = 0x10000003;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct BUTTONSSTR {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public ushort usButtonFlags;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public ushort usButtonData;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct RAWHID {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwSizHid;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwCount;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    internal struct RAWMOUSE {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public ushort usFlags;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public uint ulButtons;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public BUTTONSSTR buttonsStr;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        [FieldOffset(8)]
        public uint ulRawButtons;
        [FieldOffset(12)]
        public int lLastX;
        [FieldOffset(16)]
        public int lLastY;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        [FieldOffset(20)]
        public uint ulExtraInformation;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct RAWKEYBOARD {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public ushort MakeCode;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public ushort Flags;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public ushort Reserved;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public ushort VKey;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public uint Message;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public uint ExtraInformation;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]

    internal struct RAWINPUT {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public RAWINPUTHEADER header;
        [FieldOffset(16)]
        public RAWMOUSE mouse;
        [FieldOffset(16)]
        public RAWKEYBOARD keyboard;
        [FieldOffset(16)]
        public RAWHID hid;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct RAWINPUTHEADER {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwType;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwSize;
        public IntPtr hDevice;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int wParam;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct RID_DEVICE_INFO_HID {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwVendorId;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwProductId;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwVersionNumber;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public ushort usUsagePage;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public ushort usUsage;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct RID_DEVICE_INFO_KEYBOARD {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwType;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwSubType;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwKeyboardMode;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwNumberOfFunctionKeys;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwNumberOfIndicators;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwNumberOfKeysTotal;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct RID_DEVICE_INFO_MOUSE {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwId;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwNumberOfButtons;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwSampleRate;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int fHasHorizontalWheel;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    internal struct RID_DEVICE_INFO {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int cbSize;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public int dwType;
        [FieldOffset(8)]
        public RID_DEVICE_INFO_MOUSE mouse;
        [FieldOffset(8)]
        public RID_DEVICE_INFO_KEYBOARD keyboard;
        [FieldOffset(8)]
        public RID_DEVICE_INFO_HID hid;
    }


    public int GetDeviceID(Message message) {
        uint dwSize = 0;

        GetRawInputData(
            message.LParam,
            RID_INPUT,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            ref dwSize,
            (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUTHEADER))
        );

        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)dwSize);

        GetRawInputData(
            message.LParam,
            RID_INPUT,
            buffer,
            ref dwSize,
            (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUTHEADER))
        );

        RAWINPUT raw = (RAWINPUT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, typeof(RAWINPUT));



        uint size = (uint)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RID_DEVICE_INFO));

        GetRawInputDeviceInfo(raw.header.hDevice, 0x2000000b, IntPtr.Zero, ref size);
        IntPtr HardwareRawInfoPTR = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)size);
        GetRawInputDeviceInfo(raw.header.hDevice, 0x2000000b, HardwareRawInfoPTR, ref size);

        RID_DEVICE_INFO RawDevInfo = (RID_DEVICE_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(HardwareRawInfoPTR, typeof(RID_DEVICE_INFO));

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("hDevice: {0} HdHandle: {1}", raw.header.hDevice, RawDevInfo.mouse.dwId));

        return RawDevInfo.mouse.dwId;
    }

}
```

raw.header.hDevice & RawDevInfo.mouse.dwId are always different values.

Can anybody spot what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your struct definitions are different than those on pinvoke.net . I recommend you start from there.

Comment: Well actually i'm getting conflicting definitions from PInvoke.Net, some pages reference them the way I have done them, and others a different way. None of them are working.

Comment: Rotem, +1 for introducing me to PInvoke.Net where some sort of global standard may hopefully be attained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some trial and error, I eventually worked out the problem.

I don't fully understand why, but for some reason "mouse button down" messages in the PreFilterMessage() (and probably wndProc) override don't provide enough information to the API's to correctly determine Device/Hardware ID.

Instead I moved the mouse button detection into the class, and performed the API's on all messages coming through this filter.

I also determined that you must first call RegisterRawInputDevices() against your forms Handle for it to listen for device information.

Full working code...

Form:

```
public partial class frmQuizMaster : Form, IMessageFilter {
    clsGetInputID MouseHandler;

//  Initialization
    public frmQuizMaster() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }

    private void frmQuizMaster_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        MouseHandler = new clsGetInputID(this.Handle);
    }

    private void frmQuizMaster_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }


    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message message) {
        int HardID = MouseHandler.GetDeviceID(message);

        if (HardID > 0) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Device ID : " + HardID.ToString());
            //Return true here if you want to supress the mouse click
            //bear in mind that mouse down and up messages will still pass through, so you will need to filter these out and return true also.
        }

        return false;
    }
```

clsGetInputID:

```
class clsGetInputID {
    private const int RID_INPUT = 0x10000003;
    private const int RIDEV_INPUTSINK = 0x00000100;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    extern static uint GetRawInputDeviceInfo(IntPtr hDevice, uint uiCommand, IntPtr pData, ref uint pcbSize);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    extern static uint GetRawInputData(IntPtr hRawInput, uint uiCommand, IntPtr pData, ref uint pcbSize, uint cbSizeHeader);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    extern static bool RegisterRawInputDevices(RAWINPUTDEVICE[] pRawInputDevice, uint uiNumDevices, uint cbSize);


    [Flags()]
    public enum RawMouseFlags : ushort {
        /// <summary>Relative to the last position.</summary>
        MoveRelative = 0,
        /// <summary>Absolute positioning.</summary>
        MoveAbsolute = 1,
        /// <summary>Coordinate data is mapped to a virtual desktop.</summary>
        VirtualDesktop = 2,
        /// <summary>Attributes for the mouse have changed.</summary>
        AttributesChanged = 4
    }
    [Flags()]
    public enum RawMouseButtons : ushort {
        /// <summary>No button.</summary>
        None = 0,
        /// <summary>Left (button 1) down.</summary>
        LeftDown = 0x0001,
        /// <summary>Left (button 1) up.</summary>
        LeftUp = 0x0002,
        /// <summary>Right (button 2) down.</summary>
        RightDown = 0x0004,
        /// <summary>Right (button 2) up.</summary>
        RightUp = 0x0008,
        /// <summary>Middle (button 3) down.</summary>
        MiddleDown = 0x0010,
        /// <summary>Middle (button 3) up.</summary>
        MiddleUp = 0x0020,
        /// <summary>Button 4 down.</summary>
        Button4Down = 0x0040,
        /// <summary>Button 4 up.</summary>
        Button4Up = 0x0080,
        /// <summary>Button 5 down.</summary>
        Button5Down = 0x0100,
        /// <summary>Button 5 up.</summary>
        Button5Up = 0x0200,
        /// <summary>Mouse wheel moved.</summary>
        MouseWheel = 0x0400
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct RAWINPUTDEVICE {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public ushort usUsagePage;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public ushort usUsage;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwFlags;
        public IntPtr hwndTarget;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct RAWHID {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwSizHid;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int dwCount;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct RawMouse {
        /// <summary>
        /// The mouse state.
        /// </summary>
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public RawMouseFlags Flags;
        /// <summary>
        /// Flags for the event.
        /// </summary>
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public RawMouseButtons ButtonFlags;
        /// <summary>
        /// If the mouse wheel is moved, this will contain the delta amount.
        /// </summary>
        [FieldOffset(6)]
        public ushort ButtonData;
        /// <summary>
        /// Raw button data.
        /// </summary>
        [FieldOffset(8)]
        public uint RawButtons;
        /// <summary>
        /// The motion in the X direction. This is signed relative motion or 
        /// absolute motion, depending on the value of usFlags. 
        /// </summary>
        [FieldOffset(12)]
        public int LastX;
        /// <summary>
        /// The motion in the Y direction. This is signed relative motion or absolute motion, 
        /// depending on the value of usFlags. 
        /// </summary>
        [FieldOffset(16)]
        public int LastY;
        /// <summary>
        /// The device-specific additional information for the event. 
        /// </summary>
        [FieldOffset(20)]
        public uint ExtraInformation;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct RAWKEYBOARD {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public ushort MakeCode;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public ushort Flags;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public ushort Reserved;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public ushort VKey;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public uint Message;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public uint ExtraInformation;
    }

    public enum RawInputType {
        /// <summary>
        /// Mouse input.
        /// </summary>
        Mouse = 0,
        /// <summary>
        /// Keyboard input.
        /// </summary>
        Keyboard = 1,
        /// <summary>
        /// Another device that is not the keyboard or the mouse.
        /// </summary>
        HID = 2
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    internal struct RawInput {
        /// <summary>Header for the data.</summary>
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public RawInputHeader Header;
        /// <summary>Mouse raw input data.</summary>
        [FieldOffset(16)]
        public RawMouse Mouse;
        /// <summary>Keyboard raw input data.</summary>
        [FieldOffset(16)]
        public RAWKEYBOARD Keyboard;
        /// <summary>HID raw input data.</summary>
        [FieldOffset(16)]
        public RAWHID Hid;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct RawInputHeader {
        /// <summary>Type of device the input is coming from.</summary>
        public RawInputType Type;
        /// <summary>Size of the packet of data.</summary>
        public int Size;
        /// <summary>Handle to the device sending the data.</summary>
        public IntPtr Device;
        /// <summary>wParam from the window message.</summary>
        public IntPtr wParam;
    }


    public bool LockForBuzzersOnly = true;
    public List<int> BuzzerDevices = new List<int>();


    public int GetDeviceID(Message message) {
        uint dwSize = 0;

        GetRawInputData(
            message.LParam,
            RID_INPUT,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            ref dwSize,
            (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RawInputHeader))
        );

        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)dwSize);

        GetRawInputData(
            message.LParam,
            RID_INPUT,
            buffer,
            ref dwSize,
            (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RawInputHeader))
        );

        RawInput raw = (RawInput)Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, typeof(RawInput));
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);

        if (raw.Mouse.ButtonFlags == RawMouseButtons.LeftDown || raw.Mouse.ButtonFlags == RawMouseButtons.RightDown) {
            return (int)raw.Header.Device;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }


    public clsGetInputID(IntPtr hwnd) {
        RAWINPUTDEVICE[] rid = new RAWINPUTDEVICE[1];

        rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01;
        rid[0].usUsage = 0x02;
        rid[0].dwFlags = RIDEV_INPUTSINK;
        rid[0].hwndTarget = hwnd;

        if (!RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, (uint)rid.Length, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(rid[0]))) {
            throw new ApplicationException("Failed to register raw input device(s).");
        }
    }
}
```